# Can a present participle follow a subject?

Tags: word-order, participles

Which is correct, and why?

> some days we went on adventures — him maneuvering our scooter, me resting my chin …

or

> some days we went on adventures — he maneuvering our scooter, I resting my chin …

Comment: both are acceptable if you read them thus: [with] him ... [with] me ... / he [would be] ... I [would be] ...

Comment: What @Leon said. But certainly in this *specific* context, I would prefer the first version (the second sounds a bit "stilted"). *"We travelled all night - [him driving, me sleeping](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22him+driving+me+sleeping%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)"*. I can find *that* on the Net, but not the alternative version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are examples of [absolute constructions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_construction):

> **Absolute construction** From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia:
>
> In linguistics, an absolute construction is a grammatical
> construction
> standing apart from a normal or usual syntactical relation with other
> words or sentence elements. It can be a non-finite clause that is
> subordinate in form and modifies an entire sentence, an adjective or
> possessive pronoun standing alone without a modified substantive, or a
> transitive verb when its object is implied but not stated.
> The term absolute derives from Latin absolūtum, meaning "loosened
> from" or "separated" ...
>
> Example Usages [absolute constructions in italics]:
>
> Being a word, phrase, or construction that is isolated
> syntactically from the rest of a sentence:
>
> - *this being the case*, let us go
> - *The referee having finally arrived*, the game began....
> - *Weather permitting*, we will have a barbecue tomorrow.

[and examples not using an ing-clause:]

- *Tremulous*, the poor lad sat and watched. [standalone short adjectives sound unnatural]
- *Mine now*, the collection will be put on display to the public.

> - *All things considered*, it's not a bad idea. [Wikipedia]

- *With the referee finally on the pitch*, the game began.

More obviously related to the original example is

> *The game began*, the referee having finally arrived."

Usually, the noun group before the -ing form does not inflect for case, but this rare use of inflecting pronouns poses a problem. I'd agree with Leon that it's hard to make a decision between nominative and accusative, with the absolute construction being 'self-contained' and almost certainly elliptical. Informality would argue against using the nominative pronouns here, but then informality would argue against using *either* alternative:

> some days we went on adventures – he would manoeuvre our scooter while
> I rested my chin ...