# With + noun+noun? Does this structure work?

Tags: grammar, sentence-patterns

"With cats and dogs the most popular companion animals around the world, it’s no surprise that they are often compared to one another in the great cats vs dogs debate."

Please help me understand this part"With cats and dogs the most popular companion animals around the world"

I know how the nominative absolute works with with, however, the predicate here is a noun. Is it grammtically correct?

Comment: Yes, this is an absolute construction, the basic form being 'Aardvarks being the most popular companion animals around the world, it’s no surprise that ...'. 'With' may be included, and if chosen, 'being' may be deleted. The coordinated NP is a minor and irrelevant tweak.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Thirsty, we drank](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/254228/thirsty-we-drank/254245#254245) See also [Can a present participle follow a subject?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/153848/can-a-present-participle-follow-a-subject)

Comment: No: absolutes are non-finite clauses. This is a preposition phrase headed by the prep "with". It's just a PP functioning as an adjunct with a causal meaning.

Comment: @BillJ: Are these versions equivalent: _With X and Y..._; _X and Y being..._; and _With X and Y being..._?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is rare, but does occur. The *with* phrase is a prepositional phrase containing a verbless clause (subject + predicate, but with no verb).

The Oxford Dictionary of English Grammar p4 defines an absolute clause as:

> A non-finite or verbless clause containing its own subject,
> attached to a sentence from which it is separated by a comma (or
> commas), and not introduced by a subordinator. Also called absolute
> construction.

However, in this case, the clause is a dependent of *with*, which would put it outside this definition.

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language p1267

> Complement to *with* and *without*
>
> i*They were standing against the wall* [*with **their hands above their
> head***].
>
> ii *They were wandering around* [*without **any clothes on***].
>
> iii [*With **the children so sick***], *we weren’t able to get much
> work done*.
>
> iv *Who is that guy* [*with **his hands in his pockets***]?
>
> The [bolded] clauses have subject + predicate structure, but with no
> verb in the predicate. *With* and *without* do not license finite
> complements, but non-finites are found in addition to the verbless
> forms. The bracketed PPs function as adjunct to a clause ([i—iii]) or
> post-modifier in NP structure ([iv]). *With* is semantically similar
> to *have*, and *without* to *not have*: [i—ii], for example, entail
> *They had their hands above their heads*, *They didn’t have any clothes on*.

In the example provided, the function of the *with...* phrase would be an adjunct of reason, telling us why *it is no surprise that...*.

Though the above references do not have noun phrases as both the subject and the predicate in the verbless construction, there examples of similar to be found:

> [With **bicycles the best way to get around** and no mobile phone
> reception], there's plenty of time to relax and attune yourself to the
> idyllic surroundings. (Australia Highlights - AKDMC)
>
> [With **Jake the only occupant**], the suite is quiet compared to the hustle
> and bustle of the thirty-eight-lawyer space I shared in downtown
> Manhattan near the South Street Seaport. (One man's paradise;
> Corleone, Douglas; Minotaur Books 2010)
>
> [With **family the only social security network**], if a couple has no sons,
> they will starve to death in their old age.
> (http://www.dailykos.com/story/2012/10/10/1142939/-Never-loved-Lawrence-O-Donnell-as-much-as-today)
>
> [With **himself the sole loser by possible mistakes of judgment**],
> Washington did not have to display the public "care and caution" that
> had been the vigilant law of his anxious life in the Army.
> (Washington's Hardest Decision; Douglas Southall Freeman; Atlantic
> Monthly: 1952:)
>
> [With **Ethan the sole survivor**], the CIA believed he was the mole.
> (http://www.superherodb.com/ethan-hunt/10-10476/history/)

More commonly, *being* or *as* is inserted between the two NPs, but the usage without them does not strike me as ungrammatical.

Comment: Thanks a lot! So is it more common to say "With cats and dogs being/as the most popular companion animals..."?

Comment: In general, that construction is easier to find examples of. However, I believe the omission of _being_ / _as_ to be permissible in this case, maybe even stylistically preferable.